# Haskell-How to store the return value of a function to a variable?

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function in Haskell to return a list. I want to get the return value of the function and store in another variable for future use. The code I have written is given below

```
module Main
 where

import System.IO

    main =do
        let list=doCal


    doCal =do
        hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
        putStrLn "Give me a number (or 0 to stop):"
        num <- getLine
        let number = read num
        if number==0
            then 
                return []
            else do 
                rest <-doCal
                return (number:rest)
```

When I try to run this, I got an error

```
Cal.hs:7:9: error:
    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      let list = doCal
  |
7 |         let list=doCal
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

How to store the return value of a function to a variable in Haskell?

Comment: It's not saying `let list=doCal` is illegal; it just saying that this can't be *the last thing* in the function. You need to put something after it (e.g., print the value or something).

Comment: Haskell does not have variables like in other languages. Please do not think in terms of variables in Haskell, it *will* confuse you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same way you already did it with `rest` in `doCal`.

```
main = do
   list <- doCal
```

But you also need to have `main` do something and return a value. So you might write

```
main = do
   list <- doCal
   print list
```

This will work because `print list` returns `()`, which is a value in Haskell (its just the only value of its type).